# How to authenticate users and navigate correctly using static getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using getDerivedStateFromProps as componentWillRecieveProps is deprecated. The problem is I have a 5 stage signup process.

This is my code.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if(prevState.success !== nextProps.success && nextProps.success === true) {
  return {success: nextProps.success };
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.success !== this.props.success && this.props.success === true) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('nextpage');
  }
}
```

But the problem is when the user navigates form 'nextpage' to this this page again. Here the values of success will be true, thus won't make a difference and won't navigate. Should I update these values once I navigate to 'nextpage' and reset them?

Comment: Just speaking from experience, these methods give me headaches when they are used at a large scale. I utilized redux to avoid these problems.

Comment: How do you handle redux for signup procedures? My signup consists of 5 screens, One 1st I ask for mobile no, then confirm otp, if the user exists I redirect to home or else signup procedure

Comment: I see four screens only.